# Databinding to listview after getting json

Tags: c#, json, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to understand MVVM and having a difficult time of getting my listview to show items from an observable collection.  I'm not having problems with getting the json into the classes I have set up but having the xaml read the binding isn't working out. I'm not quite clear as to how to set this up to be able to read the properties from data2. Can someone point out to me what I'm doing wrong?

From [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/.json), I need to get each Base.Data.Children.data.title.  0-24 children, so I should be receiving 24 titles.

**Model**

```
public class Child : BindableBase
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public Data2 data { get; set; }
}

public class Data2 : BindableBase
{
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class Posts : ViewModelBase
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }

    internal static Task<Posts> GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
         <ScrollViewer x:Name="PostsScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                              Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
            <ListView x:Name="PostListBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" SelectedItem="{Binding Children}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Children.Data.title}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </ScrollViewer>
```

**ViewModel**

ViewModelBase

```
 public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Property Changed Event Handler
    public void SetPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion Property Changed Event Handler
}
```

PostViewModel

```
    public class PostsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Child> children = new ObservableCollection<Child>();
    private ObservableCollection<Data2> data = new ObservableCollection<Data2>();
    private string title;

    #region Constructor
    public PostsViewModel()
    {
        GetFrontPagePostsAsync();
    }
    #endregion Constructor

    #region Properties
    #region Children
    public ObservableCollection<Child> Children
    {
        get { return this.children; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.children)
                this.children = value;
            this.SetPropertyChanged("Children");
        }
    }
    #endregion Children
    #endregion Properties
    public async void GetFrontPagePostsAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                string content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.reddit.com/.json");
                Posts posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Posts>(content);
                foreach (var i in posts.data.children)
                {
                    children.Add(i);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e); }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firsly, I assume that your *Children* collection is not empty

Then, I think your problem is in View. It should be like this:

**View**

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="PostsScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                              Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <ListView x:Name="PostListBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" SelectedItem="{Binding Children}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.title}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>         
</ScrollViewer>
```

What was changed is the line with TextBlock.
The parent of the TextBlock (ListView) is binded to your *Children* list. This means that each child of ListView "knows" the object that it needs to render. In your case *TextBlock* knows specified *Child* object properties (depending on the item position). 
If you are binding your page to somekind of **ViewModel**, you don't need to bind each child to

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewMode.Title}" />
```

but you simply bind it to:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
```